# Hello! I'm trying to make a chart with a json received from backEnd, and I can't parse it

Tags: reactjs

This is my json:

```
[
    {
        "day": 1,
        "commentNumber": 0
    },
    {
        "day": 2,
        "commentNumber": 0
    },
    {
        "day": 3,
        "commentNumber": 0
    },
    {
        "day": 4,
        "commentNumber": 0
    },
    {
        "day": 5,
        "commentNumber": 0
    },
    {
        "day": 6,
        "commentNumber": 0
    },
    {
        "day": 7,
        "commentNumber": 0
    },
    {
        "day": 8,
        "commentNumber": 0
    }
]
```

And here is my code:

```
export default class CommentsPerDayGraph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chartData: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getStatistics();
  }

  getStatistics = () => {
    let labels = [];
    let data = [];

    CommentApi.getCommentsPerDay().then((response) => {
      let jsonProducts = JSON.parse(response.data);
      Object.keys(jsonProducts).map((key) => {
        labels.push(key);
        data.push(response.data[key]);
      });

      this.setState({
        chartData: {
          labels: labels,
          datasets: [
            {
              labels: '',
              data: data,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
              borderWidth: 1,
              hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
              hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            },
          ],
        },
      });
      console.log(this.state.chartData);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Bar data={this.state.chartData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: That's actually not the issue here, the setState call is in the `.then`.

Comment: Not really, for me the problem is that I can't build the chart based on the data I receive on apiCall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only thing you have to do is change `data.push(response.data[key]);` to `data.push(jsonProducts[key]);`

`response.data` is a string rather than the array you want to index. `jsonProducts` is the array you get once you parse the `response.data`, so you should be using that instead.

Assuming everything else of your logic is accurate because I don't have anything to base the results on, this should be the only thing you need to change.

```js
const CommentApi = {
  getCommentsPerDay() {
    return new Promise((res) =>
      res({
        data: `[
          {
              "day": 1,
              "commentNumber": 0
          },
          {
              "day": 2,
              "commentNumber": 0
          },
          {
              "day": 3,
              "commentNumber": 0
          },
          {
              "day": 4,
              "commentNumber": 0
          },
          {
              "day": 5,
              "commentNumber": 0
          },
          {
              "day": 6,
              "commentNumber": 0
          },
          {
              "day": 7,
              "commentNumber": 0
          },
          {
              "day": 8,
              "commentNumber": 0
          }
      ]`,
      })
    );
  },
};

class CommentsPerDayGraph extends React.Component {
  state = { chartData: {} };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getStatistics();
  }

  getStatistics = () => {
    let labels = [];
    let data = [];

    CommentApi.getCommentsPerDay().then((response) => {
      let jsonProducts = JSON.parse(response.data);
      Object.keys(jsonProducts).map((key) => {
        labels.push(key);
        data.push(jsonProducts[key]);
      });

      this.setState({
        chartData: {
          labels: labels,
          datasets: [
            {
              labels: '',
              data: data,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
              borderWidth: 1,
              hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
              hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            },
          ],
        },
      });
      console.log(this.state.chartData);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/*<Bar data={this.state.chartData} />*/}
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.chartData)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CommentsPerDayGraph />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: What is the error? And can you post more of what your CommentApi looks like?

Comment: This is the error: Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Sounds like the `JSON.parse` isn't seeing actual JSON. If you `console.log` the `response.data`, what does that give you exactly?

Comment: Array(30)
0: {day: 1, commentNumber: 0}
1: {day: 2, commentNumber: 0}
2: {day: 3, commentNumber: 0}
3: {day: 4, commentNumber: 0}
4: {day: 5, commentNumber: 0}
5: {day: 6, commentNumber: 0}
6: {day: 7, commentNumber: 0}
7: {day: 8, commentNumber: 0}
8: {day: 9, commentNumber: 0}
9: {day: 10, commentNumber: 0}
10: {day: 11, commentNumber: 0}
11: {day: 12, commentNumber: 0}
12: {day: 13, commentNumber: 0}

Comment: `const jsonProducts = response.data` and you should be good. Looks like the data is already an array rather than a string.

Comment: So far so good, but it still doesn't display the graph according to the data, on labels it's okay, but not on data

Comment: You might consider making that a new question and give more information like the data structure your graph is expecting.